# How do I extract nested Json Keys in C# effeciently?

Tags: c#

How can I refactor my below method? I am calling a Json Schema and returning all the keys along with their types. The second `foreach` is there because Json of type `object` means there are nested key value pairs. Below method works fine but I am hoping there is a better way to write it?

```
Dictionary<string, Type> GetPropertiesFromDataSchema(JsonSchema schema)
{
    var propMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    foreach (var prop in schema.ActualProperties)
    {
        Type type = prop.Value.Type switch
        {
            JsonObjectType.Boolean => typeof(bool),
            JsonObjectType.Number => typeof(double),
            JsonObjectType.Integer => typeof(long),
            JsonObjectType.Object => typeof(object),
            JsonObjectType.Array => typeof(Array),
            JsonObjectType.String => typeof(string),
            _ => null
        };
        if (type != null)
        {
            propMap.Add(prop.Key, type);
            if (type.FullName == "System.Object")
            {
                string parentkey = prop.Key.ToString();
                foreach (var nestedprop in prop.Value.ActualProperties)
                {
                    type = nestedprop.Value.Type switch
                    {
                        JsonObjectType.Boolean => typeof(bool),
                        JsonObjectType.Number => typeof(double),
                        JsonObjectType.Integer => typeof(long),
                        JsonObjectType.Object => typeof(object),
                        JsonObjectType.Array => typeof(Array),
                        JsonObjectType.String => typeof(string),
                        _ => null
                    };
                    string colName = parentkey + "_" + nestedprop.Key;
                    propMap.Add(colName, type);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return propMap;
}
```

Schema which I'm passing to the method is something like this:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",  
    "properties": {
    "PartitionKey": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "RowKey": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "Version": {
        "type": "string"
        },       
        "Eest": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Bulls": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "Message": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Credit": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "Read": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "SBin": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Bulls",
            "Message",
            "Credit",
            "Read",
            "SBin"
        ]
        },
        "GenericTests": {
        "type": "array"
        },
        "HostVersion": {
        "type": "string"
        },      
        "RawSampleIDData": {
        "type": "array"
        }
},
    "required": [
        "PartitionKey",
        "RowKey",
        "Version",
        "Eest",
        "GenericTests",
        "HostVersion",
        "RawSampleIDData"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Extract the switch expression into its own method (note that it's repetitive later on - and even if it wasn't repetitive, I'd still extract it into its own method). And whatever you're doing when type is not null into one or more methods.

Comment: can you please answer it with examples. easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nate's answer is good, but i would take it a step further and move the inner foreach into a recursive call, something like this:

```
// Your public method has the schema as input
Dictionary<string, Type> GetPropertiesFromDataSchema(JsonSchema schema) {
    // Create the result dictionary
    var propMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    // Call recursive method
    GetPropertyMap(schema.ActualProperties, propMap);

    return propMap;
}

private void GetPropertyMap(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, JsonSchemaProperty> properties,
   Dictionary<string, Type> propertyMap, string parentKey = null) {
    // Iterate through the properties
    foreach (var prop in properties) {
        var type = GetType(prop);

        // If the type is null (unknown) just skip the next part
        if (type == null) {
            continue;
        }

        // If parent key is specified prefix the key
        // with it otherwise just use the key
        var key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentKey) ?
            prop.Key.ToString() :
            parentKey + "_" + prop.Key.ToString();

        // Add property to map
        propertyMap.Add(key, type);

        // If it's an object (I prefer type check instead of string check)
        // Call the same method with the key as the third parameter
        if (type == typeof(object)) {
            GetPropertyMap(prop.Value.ActualProperties, propertyMap, key);
        }
    }
}

// Return the type (Credit: Nate in another answer)
private Type GetType(KeyValuePair<string, JsonSchemaProperty> prop)
{
    return prop.Value.Type switch
    {
        JsonObjectType.Boolean => typeof(bool),
        JsonObjectType.Number => typeof(double),
        JsonObjectType.Integer => typeof(long),
        JsonObjectType.Object => typeof(object),
        JsonObjectType.Array => typeof(Array),
        JsonObjectType.String => typeof(string),
        _ => null
    };
}
```

EDIT: I added some comments, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> GetPropertiesFromDataSchema(JsonSchema schema)
{
    var propMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    foreach (var prop in schema.ActualProperties)
    {
        Type type = GetType(prop);
        if (type != null)
        {
            propMap.Add(prop.Key, type);
            if (type.FullName == "System.Object")
            {
                string parentkey = prop.Key.ToString();
                foreach (var nestedprop in prop.Value.ActualProperties)
                {
                    type = GetType(nestedprop);
                    string colName = parentkey + "_" + nestedprop.Key;
                    propMap.Add(colName, type);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return propMap;
}

private Type GetType(KeyValuePair<string, JsonSchemaProperty> prop)
{
    return prop.Value.Type switch
    {
        JsonObjectType.Boolean => typeof(bool),
        JsonObjectType.Number => typeof(double),
        JsonObjectType.Integer => typeof(long),
        JsonObjectType.Object => typeof(object),
        JsonObjectType.Array => typeof(Array),
        JsonObjectType.String => typeof(string),
        _ => null
    };
}
```